# Proof that $1/(cx+d)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Part of the proof that shows linear fractional transformations are analytic, is that they are a multiplication of two analytic functions (not including $x = -d/c$):

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d} = \frac{1}{cz+d} (az+b)$$

I am not convinced (or at least it's not immediately obvious) why the second part is analytic. I can modify the function as follows:

$$\frac{1}{c/d((c/d)x + 1)} = \frac{1}{(1 - (\frac{c}{d}x))} \frac{d}{c}$$.

And the last part can be expanded as a series $\sum{((-c/d) x)^n}$. If I can show it is a power series expansion, is that enough to show the function is analytic?

Comment: Depends on your definition of an analytic function. Some authors say that a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ is analytic at a point $z_0\in\mathbb C$ if $f$ is differentiable on some neighborhood of $z_0$, so showing that $1/(cz+d)$ is analytic will boil down to questions about its differentiability.

Comment: So to show this, would I need to show (1) Cauchy equations hold and (2) f'(z) is continuous?